# change value (string manipulation) in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am reading a CSV file to Pandas DataFrame but need to be cleaned up before can be used. I need to do two things:

1. use regex to filter values
2. apply string functions such as trim, left, right, ...

For instance, DataFrame may looks like:

```
0 city_some_string_45
1 city_Other_string_56
2 city_another_string_77
```

so I need to filter (using regex) for all rows that its value start with "city" and get last two character.

the end result should looks like:

```
0 45 
1 56 
2 77
```

In another word,  logic I want to apply is: read value of cell and if starts with city (filtering with regex ie: ^city) and replace the value of cell with its two last character of the cell (eg using right string function)

Answer (score 1):

For a dataframe like this:

```
    No  city
0   0   city_some_string_45
1   1   city_Other_string_56
2   2   city_another_string_77
```

Filter the dataframe to keep the rows with city column starting with city

df = df[df.city.str.startswith('city')]

You can use str.extract to extract only the number

```
df['city'] = df.city.str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)
```

The resulting df

```
    No  city
0   0   45
1   1   56
2   2   77
```

Comment: Thanks - logic I want to apply is more like: read value of cell and if starts with city replace the value of cell with its two last character of the cell

Comment: Thanks - I used your suggestion combined with str.slice() function and it did work for this instance but I need a better way to handle this so I am thinking to write a little function and use apply(). Thanks again for your tip